# Webdriver - Error communicating with the remote browser

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am constantly getting the following error even after multiple waits etc. I am currently using firefox 26.0 and get following error. test works fine when the conditional is true but fails always gives this error if the conditional when it checks for substring in html is false. What is the reason for this weird error. I want to show correct error.

Surprisingly test works fine in my laptop(Linux mint). Server has ubuntu with firefox 26.0

```
    String abc = wd.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText();
    System.out.println(abc);
    if (!abc.contains("Narendra Modiii")) {
       System.out.println("came here");
       File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)wd).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
       FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("failedscreenshot.png"));
```

works well again

```
    String abc = wd.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText();
    System.out.println(abc);
    if (!abc.contains("Narendra Modiii")) {
      // System.out.println("came here");
       File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)wd).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
       FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("failedscreenshot.png"));
```

gives following exception

```
Jun 04, 2014 10:20:55 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
Jun 04, 2014 10:20:55 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
```

Following is my java webdriver test

```
public class classqb8ksladhq {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    FirefoxDriver wd = null;
    try {
        String Xport = System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id", ":1");
        final File firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("lmportal.deploy.firefox.path",
            "/usr/bin/firefox"));
        FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
        firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", Xport);
        wd = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, null);
        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        wd.get("http://dev.scroll.in/");
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='searchbox']/input")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5*1000);
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='searchbox']/input")).clear();
        Thread.sleep(5*1000);
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='searchbox']/input")).sendKeys("bjp");
        Thread.sleep(60*1000);
        if (!wd.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText().contains("zzzzzzzz")) {
           File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)wd).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
           FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("failedscreenshot.png"));

            throw new RuntimeException("!wd.findElement(By.tagName(\"html\")).getText().contains(\"Narendra Modiii\") is false");
        }
        System.out.println("Test ran successfully.");
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          try{
              File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)wd).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
              FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("failedscreenshot.png"));
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch(Exception e1) {
          }
       }
      }
    //wd.quit()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose its because of timeout issue, check [Configuring timeouts](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2#Configuring_timeouts_%28Version_2.21_required%29)

Comment: wd.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText().contains("zzzzzzzz") is causing problem. Am I making too many calls to the browser that it becomes unresponsive?

Comment: and Thread.sleep(60*1000) above. thread is sleeping, but when it wakes up - It may have died (c). Try to experiment with hub's '-timeout' or ' -browserTimeout'

Comment: updated the question as couldnt add everything in comment.It is giving problem during screenshot.

Comment: I am facing no issues after I installed ubuntu12.04 in new server and started running in that. I assume the combination of webdriver version, firefox version and ubuntu14 lead to this problem.